# How to have margins that fill in an entire row of tiles

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page, with tiling elements. These elements do not always fill the entire row. How can I have the margin between these elements expand so that it is the same between each element, and the margin of the edge is 3%, so that the last element has 3% of the page to the end, and the first element is 3% of the page from the beginning.

These elements are tiled using `display: inline-block`.

This is my current code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=DM Mono">
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Amiri Quran';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url('AmiriQuran-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
        unicode-range: U+0600-06FF, U+0750-077F, U+0870-088E, U+0890-0891, U+0898-08E1, U+08E3-08FF, U+200C-200E, U+2010-2011, U+204F, U+2E41, U+FB50-FDFF, U+FE70-FE74, U+FE76-FEFC;
      }
      html body {
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Amiri Quran', sans-serif;
        background-color: black;
      }
      table {
          font-size: 2em;
          display: inline-block;
  border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      td, th {
        border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 8px;
      }
      .arabic {
        font-size: 1.5em;
      }
      .english {
        font-family: 'DM Mono', sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.75em;
        color: black;
      }
      .PREFIX {
        color: #22AA22;
      }
      .SUFFIX {
        color: #AA22AA;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body dir="rtl">

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="arabic">
<span class="PREFIX">بِ</span><span class="STEM">سْمِ</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td dir="ltr" class="english">
In (the) name

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="arabic">
<span class="STEM">ٱللَّهِ</span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td dir="ltr" class="english">
(of) Allah

</td>
</tr>
</table>


<table>
<tr>
<td class="arabic">
<span class="PREFIX">ٱل</span><span class="STEM">رَّحْمَٰنِ</span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td dir="ltr" class="english">
the Most Gracious

</td>
</tr>
</table>


<table>
<tr>
<td class="arabic">
<span class="PREFIX">ٱل</span><span class="STEM">رَّحِيمِ</span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td dir="ltr" class="english">
the Most Merciful

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to use a flex-grid for that?

Comment: @johnSmith In what context? (Sorry, I'm relatively new to front-end and have the vast majority of my experience in back-end.)

Comment: Instead of using a table you could use a "flex-grid", there is a subproperty `justify-content: space-between` which does exactly what you want AFAIS  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Alright, with a slight adaptation, (placing the tables within the flex-grid), this worked well for me. If you could write this as an answer, then I can mark it as correct for people from Google.

Comment: @johnSmith However, using `em` for the row-gap property does not use the height of the items in the flex grid as `1em` bt some other mystery unit. What would this em value be relative to?

Comment: Hey thats cool that its working for you :) em will be based on the font-size of the parent element, its a little bit tricky to work with, probably using rem would be better, there are lots of good articles on the web how they work

Comment: @johnSmith Yep, I ended up using `vh`. `em` is pretty odd in its behavior.